# concatenate expression with string in ng-model directive

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, binding, angular-ngmodel

i have the below ng-repeat

```
<span ng-repeat = "x in levels">
    <input id="{{x}}" type="checkbox" ng-model="Filter.level.{{x}}" ng-true-value="{{x}}"  data-ng-false-value=""/><label for="{{x}}">{{x}}</label>
</span>
```

im facing issue with the value of ng-model directive

i tried to use it many ways but it didnt work:

```
ng-model="Filter.level.{{x}}"
```

or

```
ng-model="'Filter.level.'+{{x}}"
```

or

```
ng-model="'Filter.level.'+'{{x}}'"
```

or

```
ng-model="'Filter.level.level'+{{$index}}"
```

its work only when i use it like `ng-model="Filter.level.level1"`

but i need the value to be dynamic from `ng-repeat` like Filter.level.level1, Filter.level.level2 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should access object by index there with the help of `[]`, you can't use `{{}}`(interpolation directive) inside `ng-model`

```
ng-model="Filter.level[x]"
```